# windows Deployment TFTP transfer timeout

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, wireshark, imaging, tftp

I am hoping to get some advice on some of the WDS issues we have been having over the past 4-5 months

We have a relativity simple network topology

Out workstations on one subnet and servers across a WAN link on a separate subnet with a juniper firewall in the middle

The WDS server is 2008r2

The problem we are having is that every few weeks we seem to lose the ability to PXE boot across the firewall to the WDS server

The WDS server gives us the following error

The Following Client failed TFTP Download:

IP: 10.10.34.95
 Filename: \Boot\x64\Images\DaRT7.wim
 ErrorCode: 1460

Which seems to be related to a time out

1460 is ERROR_TIMEOUT. This message means that the client started downloading the file, but didn't finish and the server is terminating the connection since it hasn't seen any packets from the client in a long time.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/a1246f62-6a8a-482b-9323-7e02dfeab196/wds-tftp-errorcode-1460

I have a hard time believing this because it works successfully for weeks at a time.

I have looked a wire shark trace to see what is happening on the wire, and it look like the TFTP packets are transmitting until a random point and then stop.

I immediately suspect the firewall, however I'm told by our firewall people that the firewall is not configured to stop TFTP packets,
 Also I was able to successfully transfer a large using tftpd from the same server. the only difference was that it acknowledged each packet where as WDS acknowledges in a set of four

Any Advice would be greatly appreciated

Below is an example of the TFTP traffic at the point of failure

Example of traffic
[image]

To add to this I was able to obtain the trail of the tracing log

```
5772] 15:57:16: [533356][WDSTFTP] [d:\w7rtm\base\ntsetup\opktools\wds\transport\server\tftp\tftpsession.cpp:1158] Expression: , Win32 Error=0x284
 [5772] 15:57:16: [533356][WDSTFTP] [d:\w7rtm\base\ntsetup\opktools\wds\transport\server\tftp\tftpsession.cpp:1177] Expression: , Win32 Error=0x284
 [10976] 15:57:16: [533590][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[OACK]: BlkSize=512 (512), WinSize=1, Timeout=2, TSize=31124
 [10976] 15:57:18: [535290][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1625, Size=1422
 [10976] 15:57:18: [535290][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1625, DataLen=1422
 [10976] 15:57:18: [535290][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1626, Size=1422
 [10976] 15:57:18: [535290][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1626, DataLen=1422
 [10976] 15:57:18: [535290][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1627, Size=1422
 [10976] 15:57:18: [535290][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1627, DataLen=1422
 [10976] 15:57:18: [535290][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1628, Size=1422
 [10976] 15:57:18: [535290][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1628, DataLen=1422
 [14892] 15:57:18: [535384][WDSTFTP] TFTPParse[ACK]: Block#=1624
 [14892] 15:57:18: [535384][WDSTFTP] [d:\w7rtm\base\ntsetup\opktools\wds\transport\server\tftp\tftpsession.cpp:1158] Expression: , Win32 Error=0x284
 [14892] 15:57:18: [535384][WDSTFTP] [d:\w7rtm\base\ntsetup\opktools\wds\transport\server\tftp\tftpsession.cpp:1177] Expression: , Win32 Error=0x284
 [10976] 15:57:18: [535602][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[OACK]: BlkSize=512 (512), WinSize=1, Timeout=2, TSize=31124
 [11100] 15:57:20: [537303][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1625, Size=1422
 [11100] 15:57:20: [537303][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1625, DataLen=1422
 [11100] 15:57:20: [537303][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1626, Size=1422
 [11100] 15:57:20: [537303][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1626, DataLen=1422
 [11100] 15:57:20: [537303][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1627, Size=1422
 [11100] 15:57:20: [537303][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1627, DataLen=1422
 [11100] 15:57:20: [537303][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1628, Size=1422
 [11100] 15:57:20: [537303][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1628, DataLen=1422
 [11056] 15:57:20: [537365][WDSTFTP] TFTPParse[ACK]: Block#=1624
 [11056] 15:57:20: [537365][WDSTFTP] [d:\w7rtm\base\ntsetup\opktools\wds\transport\server\tftp\tftpsession.cpp:1158] Expression: , Win32 Error=0x284
 [11056] 15:57:20: [537365][WDSTFTP] [d:\w7rtm\base\ntsetup\opktools\wds\transport\server\tftp\tftpsession.cpp:1177] Expression: , Win32 Error=0x284
 [10976] 15:57:20: [537615][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000017161E0:10.10.34.115:2070] - Timeout: Max retries done, killing session.
 [10976] 15:57:20: [WDSTFTP][UDP][Ep=10.10.35.135:64302] Deleted.
 [10976] 15:57:20: [537630][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000017161E0:10.10.34.115:2070] - Endpoint Removed. Killing session.
 [10976] 15:57:20: UpdEndpoint::~UdpEndpoint = 0000000001B073A0

[10976] 15:57:20: [WDSTFTP][UDP][Ep=0] Closed
 [10976] 15:57:20: [UDPPorts] Dynamic Port 64302 freed.
 [10976] 15:57:20: [537630][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000017161E0:10.10.34.115:2070] - Shutdown
 [10976] 15:57:20: [537630][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[(null)] - Shutdown
 [11100] 15:57:22: [539315][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1625, Size=1422
 [11100] 15:57:22: [539315][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1625, DataLen=1422
 [11100] 15:57:22: [539315][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1626, Size=1422
 [11100] 15:57:22: [539315][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1626, DataLen=1422
 [11100] 15:57:22: [539315][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1627, Size=1422
 [11100] 15:57:22: [539315][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1627, DataLen=1422
 [11100] 15:57:22: [539315][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1628, Size=1422
 [11100] 15:57:22: [539315][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1628, DataLen=1422
 [6060] 15:57:22: [539393][WDSTFTP] TFTPParse[ACK]: Block#=1624
 [6060] 15:57:22: [539393][WDSTFTP] [d:\w7rtm\base\ntsetup\opktools\wds\transport\server\tftp\tftpsession.cpp:1158] Expression: , Win32 Error=0x284
 [6060] 15:57:22: [539393][WDSTFTP] [d:\w7rtm\base\ntsetup\opktools\wds\transport\server\tftp\tftpsession.cpp:1177] Expression: , Win32 Error=0x284
 [6060] 15:57:24: [541265][WDSTFTP] TFTPParse[ACK]: Block#=1624
 [6060] 15:57:24: [541265][WDSTFTP] [d:\w7rtm\base\ntsetup\opktools\wds\transport\server\tftp\tftpsession.cpp:1158] Expression: , Win32 Error=0x284
 [6060] 15:57:24: [541265][WDSTFTP] [d:\w7rtm\base\ntsetup\opktools\wds\transport\server\tftp\tftpsession.cpp:1177] Expression: , Win32 Error=0x284
 [10976] 15:57:24: [541328][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1625, Size=1422
 [10976] 15:57:24: [541328][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1625, DataLen=1422
 [10976] 15:57:24: [541328][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1626, Size=1422
 [10976] 15:57:24: [541328][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1626, DataLen=1422
 [10976] 15:57:24: [541328][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1627, Size=1422
 [10976] 15:57:24: [541328][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1627, DataLen=1422
 [10976] 15:57:24: [541328][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1628, Size=1422
 [10976] 15:57:24: [541328][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1628, DataLen=1422
 [11100] 15:57:26: [543340][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1625, Size=1422
 [11100] 15:57:26: [543340][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1625, DataLen=1422
 [11100] 15:57:26: [543340][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1626, Size=1422
 [11100] 15:57:26: [543340][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1626, DataLen=1422
 [11100] 15:57:26: [543340][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1627, Size=1422
 [11100] 15:57:26: [543340][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1627, DataLen=1422
 [11100] 15:57:26: [543340][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1628, Size=1422
 [11100] 15:57:26: [543340][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1628, DataLen=1422
 [12928] 15:57:28: [545352][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1625, Size=1422
 [12928] 15:57:28: [545352][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1625, DataLen=1422
 [12928] 15:57:28: [545352][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1626, Size=1422
 [12928] 15:57:28: [545352][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1626, DataLen=1422
 [12928] 15:57:28: [545352][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1627, Size=1422
 [12928] 15:57:28: [545352][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1627, DataLen=1422
 [12928] 15:57:28: [545352][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1628, Size=1422
 [12928] 15:57:28: [545352][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1628, DataLen=1422
 [11100] 15:57:30: [547365][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1625, Size=1422
 [11100] 15:57:30: [547365][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1625, DataLen=1422
 [11100] 15:57:30: [547365][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1626, Size=1422
 [11100] 15:57:30: [547365][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1626, DataLen=1422
 [11100] 15:57:30: [547365][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1627, Size=1422
 [11100] 15:57:30: [547365][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1627, DataLen=1422
 [11100] 15:57:30: [547365][WDSTFTP] TftpSession[0x00000000013A9DE0:10.10.34.115:7029] - Cache Hit: Block#=1628, Size=1422
 [11100] 15:57:30: [547365][WDSTFTP] TFTPConstruct[DATA]: Block#=1628, DataLen=1422
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have the DNS server and the WDS server in the same PC?
check this KB
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977512
your DNS might be "inadvertently" binding ports meant to be used by the TFTP service.

Comment: DNS was not running on the server and nothing was using port 53 oddly enough the problem seems to resolve itself after a few weeks. I never did get an explanation.  I will repost if it happens agajn